# Trying to open a device using HidDevice FromIdAsync in UWP always returns null unless using FileAccessMode.Read

Tags: uwp, hid

I can confirm that my HID device can have read and write capabilities, because this has been verified in WPF application, where one Endpoint can read and the other can read and write.

I thought it might be a permissions issue, but I defined almost every possible Usage in the manifest, and this still doesn't work.

Is there any other way to test HID besides buying SuperMUTT? (It costs 350$)

My code:

```cs
            //This method will be called on the UI thread
            private async Task OpenDevice()
            {
                string aqs = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(0x0001, 0x0005, 0xAAAA, 0xBBBB);
                //Two Endpoints are returned here, one of which can only be opened by Read, and the other cannot be opened by Read or ReadWrite
                var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
                foreach (var deviceInfo in devices)
                {
                    var access = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromId(deviceInfo.Id);
                    if (access.CurrentStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed)
                    {
                        var deviceWithReadWrite = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                        //deviceWithReadWrite is null
                        var deviceWithRead = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                        //deviceWithRead is not null
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Capabilities in Package.appxmanifest**

```
    <Capabilities>
        <DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
            <Device Id="any">
                <Function Type="usage:0001 *"/>
                <Function Type="usage:0009 *"/>
                <Function Type="usage:FF00 *"/>
                <Function Type="usage:FFF0 *"/>
                <Function Type="usage:FF80 *"/>
            </Device>
        </DeviceCapability>
    </Capabilities>
```

**HID Report Descriptor**

```
0x08,              // Usage
0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x05,        // Usage (Game Pad)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x85, 0x01,        //   Report ID (1)
0x09, 0x30,        //   Usage (X)
0x09, 0x31,        //   Usage (Y)
0x09, 0x32,        //   Usage (Z)
0x09, 0x35,        //   Usage (Rz)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x04,        //   Report Count (4)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x09, 0x39,        //   Usage (Hat switch)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x07,        //   Logical Maximum (7)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x46, 0x3B, 0x01,  //   Physical Maximum (315)
0x65, 0x14,        //   Unit (System: English Rotation, Length: Centimeter)
0x75, 0x04,        //   Report Size (4)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x42,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,Null State)
0x65, 0x00,        //   Unit (None)
0x05, 0x09,        //   Usage Page (Button)
0x19, 0x01,        //   Usage Minimum (0x01)
0x29, 0x11,        //   Usage Maximum (0x11)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0x01,        //   Logical Maximum (1)
0x75, 0x01,        //   Report Size (1)
0x95, 0x11,        //   Report Count (17)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,  //   Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF00)
0x09, 0x20,        //   Usage (0x20)
0x75, 0x03,        //   Report Size (3)
0x95, 0x01,        //   Report Count (1)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x05, 0x01,        //   Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
0x09, 0x33,        //   Usage (Rx)
0x09, 0x34,        //   Usage (Ry)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x02,        //   Report Count (2)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,  //   Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF00)
0x09, 0x21,        //   Usage (0x21)
0x95, 0x36,        //   Report Count (54)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x85, 0x05,        //   Report ID (5)
0x09, 0x22,        //   Usage (0x22)
0x95, 0x1F,        //   Report Count (31)
0x91, 0x02,        //   Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x85, 0x03,        //   Report ID (3)
0x0A, 0x21, 0x27,  //   Usage (0x2721)
0x95, 0x2F,        //   Report Count (47)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x06, 0x80, 0xFF,  //   Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF80)
0x85, 0xE0,        //   Report ID (-32)
0x09, 0x57,        //   Usage (0x57)
0x95, 0x02,        //   Report Count (2)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              // End Collection
0x06, 0xF0, 0xFF,  // Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFFF0)
0x09, 0x40,        // Usage (0x40)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x85, 0xF0,        //   Report ID (-16)
0x09, 0x47,        //   Usage (0x47)
0x95, 0x3F,        //   Report Count (63)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x85, 0xF1,        //   Report ID (-15)
0x09, 0x48,        //   Usage (0x48)
0x95, 0x3F,        //   Report Count (63)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x85, 0xF2,        //   Report ID (-14)
0x09, 0x49,        //   Usage (0x49)
0x95, 0x0F,        //   Report Count (15)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x85, 0xF3,        //   Report ID (-13)
0x0A, 0x01, 0x47,  //   Usage (0x4701)
0x95, 0x07,        //   Report Count (7)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,  //   Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF00)
0x09, 0x00,        //   Usage (0x00)
0x85, 0x10,        //   Report ID (16)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x25, 0xFF,        //   Logical Maximum (-1)
0x35, 0x00,        //   Physical Minimum (0)
0x45, 0xFF,        //   Physical Maximum (-1)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x3F,        //   Report Count (63)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x06, 0x00, 0xFF,  //   Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFF00)
0x09, 0x20,        //   Usage (0x20)
0x85, 0xDD,        //   Report ID (-35)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x3F,        //   Report Count (63)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x85, 0x0F,        //   Report ID (15)
0x09, 0x22,        //   Usage (0x22)
0x95, 0x3F,        //   Report Count (63)
0x91, 0x02,        //   Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              // End Collection
```

Comment: May I ask you also use the same API in your WPF app?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Thanks for your reply! I use [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) to get device handle, and then open the device through `new FileStream(deviceHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, bufferSize, isAsync)`

Because there is no API related to [HidDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice?view=winrt-22621) in WPF, I can't compare and test

Comment: You can try to use the [official sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess) in GitHub, and change the [DeviceCapability in manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess/cs/Package.appxmanifest#L50) into your device.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I have read the link you sent, but the main problem at present is that the device cannot be opened with read and write permissions.
Now that I've tried all the combinations of usagePage+usageId to no effect, I'm not sure whether the problem is manifest or whether UWP has special requirements for the device's HID report descriptor.